# Sort an Input List of Floating Numbers.

Tags: python, sorting, floating-point

I'm trying to write a code that takes an input of floating numbers from a user, sort the values in ascending order. I tried a options found in Stack Overflow, but its still not working. This is a piece of my code:

```
if option == 'f': 
    x = input() 
    y = (sorted(x, key=lambda z: float(z)))   # sort float ascending 
    print(y)
```

.

```
>>> Input: 5.0 , 4.9 , 3.1, 0.5    
Output: 0.5, 3.1, 4.9, 5.0
```

How can i get list of floating point numbers and print the sorted output?

Comment: You can't just take the raw input, you have to split it into separate numbers first.

Comment: Is there an error?  Are you on python2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I'm using python 3.5. The answer from mhawke works but I'm still trying to tweak a few things. This is the code I have so far. But I get an error message when I enter a list of floats separated by a space.                                      `if option == 'f':`
 `x = (s.strip() for s in input().split(' '))`
 `y = (sorted(x, key=lambda z: float(z)))`    # sort float ascending 
 `print (y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the input *string* into separate floating point number strings, then sort on their float value. The following code splits on commas and removes any whitespace before sorting:

```
if option == 'f': 
    x = (s.strip() for s in input().split(','))
    y = (sorted(x, key=lambda z: float(z)))   # sort float ascending 
    print(y)
```

This outputs:

```
['0.5', '3.1', '4.9', '5.0']
```

You can also print it like this:

```
>>> print(', '.join(y))    # using join()
0.5, 3.1, 4.9, 5.0
>>> print(*y, sep=', ')    # Python 3 style print function
0.5, 3.1, 4.9, 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you! this is working. I still trying to tweak a few things. Because I'm still get some errors depending how I enter the floating numbers. If I enter one float it works. If I enter a list separated by a comma or space. I get a Value Error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "qwikifwlistmgr", line 48, in <module>`
    `y = (sorted(x, key=lambda z: float(z)))    # sort float ascending` 
  `File "qwikifwlistmgr", line 48, in <lambda>`
    `y = (sorted(x, key=lambda z: float(z)))    # sort float ascending` 
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4.3,24.4'`

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a string of type `str`. You should split it and convert to `float`.
@mhawke gives a good example.